# covarinace of two simple rdd in Apache spark

Tags: python, apache-spark

I was using ApacheSpark, I created two simple rdd, calculated their mean and now I wanted to calculate the covariance of the values of two rdd. But when I enter the instruction as shown in the body it produces a syntax error. I tried to debug it but wasn't able. How will I solve this issue?

```
rddX = sc.parallelize(range(100))
rddY = sc.parallelize(range(100))

meanX = rddX.sum()/rddX.count()
meanY = rddY.sum()/rddY.count()

rddXY = rddX.zip(rddY)

rddXY.take(10)

covXY = rddXY.map(lambda (x,y): (x-meanX)*(y-meanY)).sum()/rddXY.count()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `cov` function as shown below

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import rand
df = sqlContext.range(0, 10).withColumn('rand1', rand(seed=10)).withColumn('rand2', rand(seed=27))

df.stat.cov('rand1', 'rand2')
0.009908130446217347
```

More details can be found here - https://databricks.com/blog/2015/06/02/statistical-and-mathematical-functions-with-dataframes-in-spark.html

Comment: Thanks @jayadeep

Comment: If this answer was useful please do accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is of tuple unpacking. the above syntax is good for python 2, which the instructor of the course used during the training. The solution that worked for me is stated below:

1. use x__y instead of (x,y), note its double underscore
2. pass in the values of x, y to the lambda as x__y[0] and x__y[1].